# Where is word Allah used to invoke Maa Durga?

Tags: identification-request, durga, evidence

Well in one of recent videos I heard Jagadguru Shankaracharya Swami Nischalananda claiming that the  '**Allah is a Sanskrit word which is used to invoke Maa Durga**'

Does any one have any information about where exactly is it being used? I mean which shloka or stotra or mantra or stuti?

Make sure to answer the question from valid and authentic resources.

Comment: The Shankaracharya of Puri seems to have confused the Sanskrit इला with the Arabic Al-Ilah (colloquially termed as Allah). The Sanskrit term does denote Bhagavati Durga as stated here in https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/ila but the usage is exceedingly rare. The Arabic term Ilah is cognate of the Jewish Yahweh & there is no evidence for either term being influenced by Sanskrit. It seems that the Shankaracharya of Puri was too naive in this case to fall prey to some sort of false propaganda, because he has never shown any acquaintance with Islamic texts in the past.

Comment: *correction, not with Yahweh but with the Jewish Elohim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw a similar statement [in this fb post also](https://m.facebook.com/teachings10/photos/a.478045305651929/907186639404458/?type=3).

It's Ila or Ida. Who is the daughter of Manu and the wife of the planet Buddha.

Ila is also the name of Mata Rudrani Amba.

For example.:

**Rig Veda 2.1.11.:**

> *त्वम॑ग्ने॒ अदि॑तिर्देव दा॒शुषे॒ त्वं होत्रा॒ भार॑ती वर्धसे गि॒रा । **त्वमिळा॑** श॒तहि॑मासि॒ दक्ष॑से॒ त्वं वृ॑त्र॒हा व॑सुपते॒ सर॑स्वती ॥*
>
> *“You, divine Agni, are Aditi to the donor of the oblation; you are Hotā and Bhāratī, and thive by praise; **you are Iḷā** of a hundred winters to him who makes you gifts; you, lord of wealth, are the destroyer of Vṛtra, Sarasvatī.”*

**Commentary by Sāyaṇa: Ṛgveda-bhāṣya.:**

> **Iḷā of a hundred winters: tvam iḷā;**
>
> Śatahimāsi = the earth of unlimited duration, aparimitakāla bhūmiḥ; destroyer of Vṛtra: vṛtrahā = destroyer of sin.

**Meaning.:**

> iḍā < iḍ
> [noun], instrumental, singular, feminine
>
> **“refreshment; libation.”**

Hope this helps.